# Reading floats in tiff image or RGB-raw image in C language

Tags: c, floating-point, tiff, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to access the 32 bit floats in a tiff file generated with Rawtherapee. Gimp can open the tiff and it looks fine.

I got the tif header size from both ExifTool and tiffdump and they both match at 13,022 bytes. They also agree on the width and height of 4916
wide by 7370 tall and a bitmap size of 434,771,040.

```
I wrote a small C program to test reading and decoding the pixel at (0,0):
- Open the file in binary mode
- Seek past the 13022 byte header
- Read the first pixel of 3 floats, 12 bytes into memory
- printf the results with a "%f" format
```

The pixel at (0, 0) has RGB values of (22.7%, 31.0% and 0%) in RawTherapee. The floats should be in the [0.0 .. 1.0] range.

The floats decoded look like random numbers. So I converted the .tif to a raw, RGB bitmap with ImageMagick did the same procedure except with a seek of 0 as there is no header. The results again looked random and did not match the tiff pixel.

"Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon."
This is NOT CODE.

I converted the RGB file to a JPG with ImageMagick and the JPG is fine so the RGB file must be fine too.

The float tif appears to have only 1 strip and the "StripByteCounts" is a scalar, not an array. The StripByteCounts matches the expected RGB.
size of $xres * $yres * 12 bytes/pixel.

The RGB file size exactly matches the TIFF StripByteCounts:
lsr -s pf-274887.edge.f32.tif.rgb  ->  434771040
mult 4916 7370 12            434771040

I wrote a small C program to try to access the bitmaps (see code below).
I get garbled data and a mismatch between the tiff and the RGB:

```
----------
Running:
float.pixel.test
pf-274887.edge.f32.tif: Seek -> 13022, Read 3:  
float:  B -0.000000, G -0.000003, R 0.000000 ->  
UINT32: B 2634654270, G 3059326270, R  457414589

pf-274887.edge.f32.tif.rgb: Seek -> 0, Read 3:  
float:  B 35650027520.000000, G 1450022528.000000, R 0.000000 ->  
UINT32: B 1359269508, G 1319951149, R          0

----
IMAGEMAGICK CONVERSION: ------
convert pf-274887.edge.f32.tif -depth 32 RGB:pf-274887.edge.f32.tif.rgb
convert  -size 4916x7370 -depth 32  RGB:pf-274887.edge.f32.tif.rgb pf-        274887.edge.f32.jpg
The .JPG looks perfect. 

SIZE CHECK: ------
lsr -s pf-274887.edge.f32.tif.rgb  ->  434771040
mult 4916 7370 12                      434771040

EXIFTOOL DATA:  ------
exiftool -s -all pf-274887.edge.f32.tif | \
sort | egrep "^ImageSize|^Strip|SampleFormat"
ImageSize                       : 4916x7370
SampleFormat                    : Float; Float; Float
StripByteCounts                 : 434771040
StripOffsets                    : 13022  << Scalar,not array

TIFFDUMP DATA:  ------
tiffdump pf-274887.edge.f32.tif | \
    egrep "BitsPerSample|ImageLength|ImageWidth|^Strip"
ImageWidth (256) SHORT (3) 1<4916>
ImageLength (257) SHORT (3) 1<7370>
BitsPerSample (258) SHORT (3) 3<32 32 32>
StripOffsets (273) LONG (4) 1<13022>
StripByteCounts (279) LONG (4) 1<434771040>

=========================================================
float.pixel.test  c program:
```

I expected that reading the RGB file without any TIFF complications should give reasonable results. The values must surely be stored in the IEEE 754 floating point format identical to how the data are stored in memory.

The intent is to learn how to get the values, not to just get the values in this one case. Getting the values from the RGB would be a good step forward.

I tried reading pixels (0, 0) and (3, 3) and got similar results;  floats not in the [0.0 .. 1.0] range and raw-RGB values not matching the tiff values.

I converted the tif to a RGB and then converted the RGB to a jpg and the jpg looked perfect so the RGB must also be intact.

I used size_t on all of the seeks and freads. And I checked for errors on the number of floats read by fread with the number requested. And I checked the floats for NAN mangling. All floats were numbers, just not in the right range.

I also expected the tiff pixel to exactly match the corresponding RGB pixel but there is no similarity. I simplified the test program to do nothing extra.

One of the answers below is to use "libtiff". Libtiff will not help with the RGB file reading problem. I don't want to go to Whole Foods and buy a pound of Salmon. I want to catch it myself.

Here is the C code program with 4 spaces prepended:

```
   // =============================================================================
// Read and decode a specific pixel in a float32 tiff
/*
 gcc -g -O0 -m64  bln/float.pixel.test.c -lm -lz                                  -o bln/float.pixel.test
 
*/

#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdint.h"
#include <math.h>

int osrp(char *ifn, size_t soff, size_t numf);  // Open, Seek, Read, Print

// =============================================================================
void main(int argc, char *argv[])  {
char tfn[]={ "pf-274887.edge.f32.tif" };      // From RawTherapee
char rfn[]={ "pf-274887.edge.f32.tif.rgb" };  // From ImageMagick
size_t toff=13022ll, roff=0, pixoff=0; // Tif and raw-RGB header Offsets 
int imgx=3, imgy=3, imgw=4916, pix_bytes=12;
    pixoff = (imgy * imgw + imgx) * pix_bytes;  // Byte offet to pixel (3,3)
    pixoff = 0ll;  // Try pixel (0, 0)
    osrp(tfn, toff+pixoff, 3);  // Open, seek, read, print
    osrp(rfn, roff+pixoff, 3);  // FileName, seek_OFFset, #_floats per pixel
    exit(0);                    // 
}  // End Main(). 
// =============================================================================


// =============================================================================
// Open, seek, read, print. Expect floats in (0.0 .. 1.0) range
// Check for errors in number of floats read and NAN on their values
int osrp(char *ifn, size_t soff, size_t numf)  {
union  {  // Overlay floats and 32 bit unsigned ints
    float    fpix[4];  // Holds 1 pixel
    uint32_t ipix[4];  // UI32 and float share same bits    
} fiu;             // Float-Int-Union
FILE *ifp;         // Image_File_Pointer
int ii, numnan=0;  // Number of NANs, Not_A_Numbers
size_t numr;       // uint64_t

    ifp = fopen(ifn, "rb");      // Read Image in Binary mode
    fseek(ifp, soff, SEEK_SET);  // Seek to start of bitmap data
                                 
    // Read numf * 4 bytes from bitmap, store in uint/float union
    numr = fread((void *)fiu.fpix, sizeof(float), numf, ifp);  // 3*4=12B  
    fclose(ifp); 
    if(numr != numf)  {  
        printf("ERROR! NumR %llu != NumF %llu\n", numr, numf);  }

    printf("%s: Seek -> %lld, Read %llu: \nfloat:  B %8.6f, G %8.6f, R %8.6f -> \nUINT32: B %10u, G %10u, R %10u\n",
        ifn, soff, numf, 
        fiu.fpix[0], fiu.fpix[1], fiu.fpix[2],
        fiu.ipix[0], fiu.ipix[1], fiu.ipix[2]);

    for(ii=0; ii < numf; ii++)  {  // Check for Non-Number floats
        if(isnan(fiu.fpix[ii]))  {  numnan++;  }  // Count NANs
    }
    if(numnan == 0)  {  printf("\n");  return(0);  }
    printf("%d floats, %d are NANs!\n\n", numf, numnan);
    return(numnan);
}
```

Comment: What is the endianess of the data in the TIFF? See the **Byte Order** section here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF

Comment: Maybe you can share your original TIFF - Google Drive or Dropbox would be ideal.

Comment: There seem to be some misconceptions in your question. Sharing your image would help considerably.

Comment: [Cross Post](https://discuss.pixls.us/t/accessing-float32-pixels-from-tiff-or-tiff-rgb-raw-in-pure-c-language/36057)

Answer (score 2):

I would not read TIFF files directly. It's a complex format, and even worse, extremely flexible. TIFF makes writing easy (you can write almost any data layout as a TIFF file) but reading hard (data can be presented in almost any way and your reader has to potentially handle all the many, many, many combinations).

No one (I think) has ever written a TIFF reader than can load all possible TIFFs. Even libtiff itself will fail for many obvious variations. You might get it working for this specific file, but it'll fail for a float tiff written by (probably) any other program, and it'll probably fail if rawtherapee ever modify their tiff writer, even slightly.

I would use libtiff, or even better, use a high level library that can hide most of the ugliness for you.

For example, [libvips](https://www.libvips.org/) supports float pixels and can read and write float TIFFs. It'll read all baselevel TIFFs and most of the variations in common use.

```
$ vips colourspace k2.jpg x.tif scrgb
$ tiffinfo x.tif
=== TIFF directory 0 ===
TIFF Directory at offset 0x21fc008 (35635208)
  Image Width: 1450 Image Length: 2048
  Resolution: 72.009, 72.009 pixels/inch
  Bits/Sample: 32
  Sample Format: IEEE floating point
  Compression Scheme: None
  Photometric Interpretation: RGB color
  Orientation: row 0 top, col 0 lhs
  Samples/Pixel: 3
  Rows/Strip: 128
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
```

That's turning an regular 8 bit JPEG into scRGB colourspace, where pixels are linear 0 - 1, and saving as TIFF. You can see from the `tiffinfo` output that it's a simple float TIFF and probably similar to your file.

You can read out pixels with eg.:

```
$ vips getpoint x.tif 10 10
0.00303527 0 0.000303527
```

To check their value.

You can read images into large C arrays with perhaps:

```
/* Compile with:
 *
 *      gcc -g -Wall getpoint.c `pkg-config vips --cflags --libs`
 */

#include <vips/vips.h>

int
main( int argc, char **argv )
{
        VipsImage *image;
        int x; 
        int y; 
        float *array;
        size_t size_in_bytes;
        int i;

        if( VIPS_INIT( argv[0] ) )
                vips_error_exit( NULL );

        if( argc != 4 )
                vips_error_exit( "usage:\n\t%s image x y", argv[0] );

        if( !(image = vips_image_new_from_file( argv[1],  
                "access", VIPS_ACCESS_SEQUENTIAL,
                NULL )) )      
                vips_error_exit( NULL );
        if( image->BandFmt != VIPS_FORMAT_FLOAT )
                vips_error_exit( "not a float image" );
        
        x = atoi( argv[2] );
        y = atoi( argv[3] );
        
        if( !(array = vips_image_write_to_memory( image, &size_in_bytes )) )
                vips_error_exit( NULL );
        
        printf( "pixel %d, %d:\n", x, y );
        for( i = 0; i < image->Bands; i++ ) 
                printf( "%d) %g\n", 
                        i,
                        array[image->Bands * (x + y * image->Xsize) + i]);
        
        free( array );
        g_object_unref( image );

        return( 0 );
}
```

I see:

```
$ ./a.out x.tif 10 10
pixel 10, 10:
0) 0.00303527
1) 0
2) 0.000303527
```